# how can i get ModificationRequestChartData correctly in kendo ui

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am not getting date correctly on x-axis's am getting June 3 date after June 9 on x-axis..i used kendo UI in angular I am attaching the code sand box link..
https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-paper-7sq8s8?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:1550-1578

I would like the answer that how can I get June 3 after June 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `{ RequestedUpdatedDate: "Jun 03", RequestCount: null },` to newRequestChartData it should show up for you.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-mcclintock-7l8g8w?file=/src/app/app.component.ts:550-568

Kendo is creating the x-axis labels from newRequestChartData first, then adding any additional x-axis labels needed from ModificationRequestChartData at the end.

If possible you could try having both of your data sets have matching categoryField with null values.